# Does this give any indication that Ensembles is saving CD to iCloud?

Tags: icloud, ensembles

I found this in ~/Library/Mobile Documents on my Mac:

[image: image of local Mobile Documents directory]

The *Baselines* folder appears to contain my two records from my CD store, but is difficult to read.  My question is:  is this a valid way of checking to see if changes are being persisted to iCloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a useful way to track what is happening, yes. The files are in JSON format, so they can be read with a standard editor like TextMate.

If you use TextMate's JSON reformatting, they become easy to read and understand. Very useful for debugging, along with the logging levels built into Ensembles (e.g. verbose level is good for debugging).

You should bear in mind that when the data is put in Mobile Documents, it can take a little while to actually upload to the cloud. But if you wait, it should happen, and the data should also appear in Mobile Documents on other devices.